# Code skipps lines after setLayoutManager in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have never seen like this before. There is no error or exception the code just skipps some line.

I have a class which is doing something and when it's done returns with an `Adapter` and it's working fine the adapter contains the correct number and returns with it correctly. After that in my `Fragment` I'm trying to use this `Adapter` with a `RecyclerView` and create a list. Here is my fragment:

```
public class ServicesFragment extends Fragment {

ArrayList<Item> list;
public RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
public RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
public ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
DownloadDataThread downloadDataThread;
public static boolean dataisready;
ProgressDialog dialog;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_service, parent, false);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.services_recycler_view);
    list = new ArrayList<Item>();
    list.add(0,new Item());
    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(list);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    downloadDataThread = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).downloadDataThread;


    final ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    Runnable helloRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            dataisready = downloadDataThread.ready;
            if(dataisready){
                itemAdapter = downloadDataThread.getItemAdapter();
                Log.d("THREAD","adapter " + itemAdapter);
                readAndLoadList(itemAdapter);
                executor.shutdown();
            }
            Log.d("THREAD","nézem "+dataisready);
        }
    };
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(helloRunnable, 0, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    return v;
}

private void readAndLoadList(ItemAdapter itemAdapter1){
    itemAdapter = itemAdapter1;
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d("THREAD"," adaptert22 "+itemAdapter.getItemCount());
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    Log.d("THREAD","muszáfá0 "+ mRecyclerView);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Log.d("THREAD","muszáfá1 "+ mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    // And after that the other logs never shows up

    Log.d("THREAD","muszáfá2 "+ mLayoutManager);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Log.d("THREAD","muszáfá3 "+ mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    Log.d("THREAD","muszáfá4 ");
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    Log.d("THREAD","muszáfá5 ");
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.invalidate();
    mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
    Log.d("THREAD","lássuk az adaptert33 "+mRecyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
}
```

}

So as you can see I'm checking in every 200 millisecond that the adapter is ready or not and when it's ready I'm returning with it's adapter and trying to load the `RecyclerView` but after that line : `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);˛` the other logs never shows up.

Before you ask me I'm created a complete RecyclerView and load in the beginning of the `onCreateView` because I always got an error for RecyclerView but before I have added that it was also bad.

Have you any idea whats going on here?

Comment: It looks like `readAndLoadList()` is being called from your threadpool thread but is updating the view (which should only be done from the UI thread).  You'd likely be better off using a callback than polling for data

Comment: I think you are right. Could please tell me more specific about callback? What do you mean?